# Why am I getting this error: IndexError: string index out of range, when that's not the case

Tags: python, error-handling, runtime-error

Open a and read it line by line. For each line, split the line into a list of words using the split() method. The program should build a list of words.For each word on each line check to see if the word is already in the list and if not, then append it to the list. When the program completes, sort the list in descending order and print the resulting words in the list.

The file had the following information:
"But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief"

```
count = 0
index_i = 0
index_j = 0
myFile = open("C:/Users/PDS/Sample File for Task_Session7.txt", "r")
#appending
for line in myFile:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split()
    if (count == 0):
        myList = line
        count += 1
    else:
        myList.extend(line)
print("Before Sorting: ",myList,"\n")
index = len(myList)
print("No of words in the list:", index)
#checking for duplicate
for i in myList:
    index_i += 1
    index_j = 0
    print("index_i :",index_i)
    if (index_i < index):
        for j in myList:
            if (index_j < index-1):
                print("index_j :",index_j)
                if (myList[index_i - 1] == myList[index_j+1]):
                    myList = myList.pop(index_j)
            else:
                break
            index_j += 1
    else:
         break                 
myList.sort()
myList.reverse()
print("After Sorting: ",myList)
myFile.close()
```

I'm getting this error at i=2 and j=2:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [170], in <cell line: 22>()
    28 if (index_j < index-1):
    29     print("index_j :",index_j)
--->30     if (myList[index_i - 1] == myList[index_j+1]):
    31         myList = myList.pop(index_j)
    32 else:

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: exception happen because `"But"[3]`  and string "But" only has element indexes of  0,1,2

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

Lists are 0 index based. So your last index in a list is one less than you are expecting. If you replace the following line

```
for i in myList:
```

with

```
for index in range(len(myList)):
```

It should work, since range starts at 0 and does not include the ending value, so your index will run from 0 to (len(myList)-1).

Answer (score 0):

This script needs a good refactor.

This business here:

```
'''
count = 0
myFile = open("C:/Users/PDS/Sample File for Task_Session7.txt", "r")
for line in myFile:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split()
    if (count == 0):
        myList = line
        count += 1
    else:
        myList.extend(line)
myFile.close()
'''
```

It can be reduced to this:

```
filePath = "C:/Users/PDS/Sample File for Task_Session7.txt"
                 
with open(filePath, "r") as myFile:
 text = myFile.read()

myList = text.split()
```

The next part of your code looks like an attempt to create a list without duplicates:

```
'''
index_i = 0
index_j = 0
for i in myList:
    index_i += 1
    index_j = 0
    print("index_i :",index_i)
    if (index_i < index):
        for j in myList:
            if (index_j < index-1):
                print("index_j :",index_j)
                if (myList[index_i - 1] == myList[index_j+1]):
                    myList = myList.pop(index_j)
            else:
                break
            index_j += 1
    else:
         break
'''
```

All of that business could be reduced to one much simpler line:

```
uniqueList = list(set(myList))
```

Finally, this business here could be simplified:

```
'''
myList.sort()
myList.reverse()
'''
```

to this:

```
myList.sort(reverse=True)
```

Putting this all together with print statements produces this:

```
filePath = "C:/Users/PDS/Sample File for Task_Session7.txt"
                 
with open(filePath, "r") as myFile:
 text = myFile.read()

myList = text.split()
uniqueList = list(set(myList))

print("List Before Sorting:", myList); print()
print("Number of words in the list:", len(myList)); print()
print("List After Removing Duplicates:", uniqueList); print()
print("Number of unique words in the list:", len(uniqueList)); print()

myList.sort(reverse=True)
print("List After Sorting: ", myList)
```

Here is the output:

```
'List Before Sorting:', ['But', 'soft', 'what', 'light', 'through', 'yonder', 'window', 'breaks', 'It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun', 'Arise', 'fair', 'sun', 'and', 'kill', 'the', 'envious', 'moon', 'Who', 'is', 'already', 'sick', 'and', 'pale', 'with', 'grief']

'Number of words in the list:', 33

'List After Removing Duplicates:', ['through', 'Arise', 'It', 'fair', 'envious', 'sick', 'sun', 'east', 'and', 'pale', 'soft', 'Who', 'grief', 'But', 'breaks', 'already', 'is', 'kill', 'the', 'with', 'moon', 'what', 'yonder', 'light', 'window', 'Juliet']

'Number of unique words in the list:', 26

'List After Sorting: ', ['yonder', 'with', 'window', 'what', 'through', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'sun', 'sun', 'soft', 'sick', 'pale', 'moon', 'light', 'kill', 'is', 'is', 'is', 'grief', 'fair', 'envious', 'east', 'breaks', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'already', 'Who', 'Juliet', 'It', 'But', 'Arise']
```